# why MongoDB cannot nest $ under $in

Tags: arrays, mongodb

In MongoDB queries such as

```
db.pokemon.find( {combats: {$in:[ {"$elemMatch":{opponent:26,winner:2}},
                                   {"$elemMatch":{opponent:64,winner:2}} ]} } )
```

return

```
MongoServerError: cannot nest $ under $in
```

What is the logic behind this error? I know that this query can be replaced by something equivalent without `$` under `$in`, but I don't understand the reason of this limitation. Notice that if we replace `$in` by `$all` in the same query there is no error.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if you want *both `combat` docs* to be present or *either* one. If you meant both (**AND**), then your existing query with `$all` does that.

`$in` is effectively already (kind of) doing an Element Match. So it *does* make sense that `$elemMatch` nested under `$in` wouldn't work.

If you want to use `$in`, then provide your objects as-is:

```js
db.pokemon.find({
  combats: {
    $in: [
      { opponent: 26, winner: 2 },
      { opponent: 64, winner: 2 }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBl35FSbE1W)

‼ However, this is **not recommended** since you can't do partial matches or if the fields are out of order in the query vs data. [From the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document):

> MongoDB does not recommend equality matches on embedded documents because the operations require an exact match of the specified `<value>` document, including the field order.

As an example, adding a third player, with the fields out of order, the query doesn't provide them in the result:

```js
{
  _id: 3,
  combats: [
    { opponent: 128, winner: 1 },
    { winner: 2, opponent: 64 }
  ]
}
```

[Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VgkT2Ctw-4t); with the same query as above, player `_id = 3` does not appear in the results.

But with `$or` & `$elemMatch`, they do:

```js
db.pokemon.find({
  $or: [
    { combats: { $elemMatch: { opponent: 26, winner: 2 } } },
    { combats: { $elemMatch: { opponent: 64, winner: 2 } } }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground 3](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L-eFPzgkYDx): notice that **changing the field order in the data still works**.

The same thing without `$elemMatch` [playground 4](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sOw0o9QfoRw) doesn't include player `_id=3`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. However I thought that `$in` represented in fact an `$or`, that is that `db.t.find( {k: {$in:[c1,c2 ]} } )` could be automatically replaced by `db.t.find({  $or: [ {k: c1},  { k: c2}  ]})` . The `$in` definition in the docs: *If the field holds an array, then the  $in operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array*, for that reason I still don't fully get why the `$in` version returns an error while the `$or` equivalent (Playground 3) works.